# Displaying a specific number of images from the data fetched through database

Tags: php, html

I am trying to display images that are fetched from the database. So, the pattern of the images that I need to print goes like this.

Row-1: 3 images 
Row-2: 2 images 
Row-3: 4 images 
Repeat.

I am able to display data in 3-2-3 form using the condition as odd and even.

```
$id=$SITE['site_settings']->cloud_site_id;
$gal="SELECT gallery_id, gallery_image_url from `cloud_site_gallery_images` where `cloud_site_id`= $id and gallery_image_status=1;";
$res = $DB->query($gal);

<?php $count = 1; 
 $row_index=1;
    if($row_index%2==1)
    {
        foreach($res as $gallery_image)

        { ?>

        <li class="gal-row<?php echo $row_index; ?> gal-img gal<?php echo $gallery_index++; ?>"><a class="th" href="<?php echo WWW_GALLERY_IMAGE_PATH.'original/'.$gallery_image->gallery_image_url; ?>"><img src="<?php echo WWW_GALLERY_IMAGE_PATH.'original/'.$gallery_image->gallery_image_url; ?>"></a></li>
            <?php 
            $count++;
            if($count==3)
                break;
        }
        $row_index++;
    }
```

I get the required result for the first row. But, how do I go on automating the second and further rows.

Also can someone please suggest how can I go through about printing the remaining images.

Comment: there is a missing semicolon after your first `$count = 1;` row

Comment: You didn't use `$res` anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following logic to print result desired format.

Row-1: 3 images

Row-2: 2 images

Row-3: 4 images

Repeat.

```
| img1 | img2 | img3 |
| img4 | img5 |
| img6 | img7 | img8 | img9 |


 $imgArray = array('1' => 'img1' , 
                    '2' => 'img2' ,
                    '3' => 'img3' ,
                    '4' => 'img4' ,
                    '5' => 'img5' ,
                    '6' => 'img6' ,
                    '7' => 'img7' , 
                    '8' => 'img8' ,
                    '9' => 'img9' 
                    );

$temp = array();    
$i=1;
$j=0;
$k=0;

foreach ($imgArray as $key => $value) {

    if($i==4) {
        var_dump($temp);
        $temp = array();
        $j=1;
        $i=0;
    }

    if($j==3){
        var_dump($temp);
        $temp = array();
        $k=1;
        $i=0;
        $j=0;
    }

    if($k==5){
        var_dump($temp);
        $temp = array();
        $i=1;
        $k=0;
        $j=0;
    }

if($i>0)
    $i++;

if($j>0)
    $j++;

if($k>0)
    $k++;

$temp[$key] = $value;
}
```

Comment: But I cannot have static data. The data is being fetched from database.

Comment: It's a generic function, you can replace imgArray with your dynamic array